# How can I search Findmypast for children born to a given set of parents?

Tags: findmypast, product-support

[Findmypast](http://www.findmypast.co.uk) is an excellent resource for UK records, but is there an easy way that I can find the [parish baptisms](http://www.findmypast.co.uk/search/parish-records/baptisms?tab=1) for **any** child born to a given set of parents? It is easy to do on Ancestry and FamilySearch by adding the names of parents, the expected surname of the children, and leaving the given name field blank. But I cannot see any way to do this on Findmypast besides entering in just the surname. That usually brings up too many results, especially since the parents names are not shown in the search results list. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

I am a long-time user of findmypast.co.uk but I know of no way to do this. The Filter dialog shown above is not something I've ever seen so I suspect it is not available through the ".co.uk" interface.

I suspect that their UK parish records have come from many different sources and so the level of indexing is variable, to say the least. If all of them were adequately and consistently indexed then there would be no impediment to providing multiple search criteria, just as their excellent census searches provide.

I have personally had very little success from their parish records though. As well as poor search facilities, the level of detail presented for various matches is variable (sometimes being no more than what was entered in the search boxes) and with few images.

This is definitely one area where Ancestry have better support.

Answer (score 1):

I can say that if you're searching in **Cheshire** and want to search by parents - use FamilySearch (FS) first, as FS provided the indexes for the images on FindMyPast (FMP), and they continue to host the indexes. Also - in those cases where the FS indexes were, shall we say, sub-optimal, with the consequent result that the FMP displays are not located to a church, then the FS indexes will usually reveal the church in question.